# What's the PVV position on trade with China?

Tags: china, parties, trade, netherlands

How much decoupling [if any] are they saying they are after? E.g. do they want to limit imports from China, if so how much and by what means? Likewise for exports, e.g. do they support limiting tech export from the Netherlands to China, or even others?

I found a poll [here](https://www.clingendael.org/sites/default/files/2021-03/Barometer_Alert_Dutch_views_%20of_China_March2021.pdf) from 2020 on Dutch attitudes to China, more broadly, but it doesn't help a lot with respect to the PVV, except it does note (p. 5) the PVV voters were among the most China-skeptic in Sep 2020, but they were also among the "least concerned" about China in Feb of that year.

FWTW, there's a [page in Dutch from 2021](https://www.ewmagazine.nl/buitenland/achtergrond/2021/02/dit-staat-in-verkiezingsprogrammas-over-china-805318/) that apparently says that

> China is not mentioned once in the PVV's election manifesto.

So, I guess it's not a central issue for them, but maybe they said something elsewhere nonetheless.

Comment: They are a bit Anti-china due to them being pro-USA/NATO and see communism as a threat. But it's not a focus point for them so beside some fleeting remarks nothing official.